# Why a class cannot has reference of a const char string?

Tags: c++, raii

I have these code and I found `s` will get invalid if it is a C-styled const string:

```cpp
class has_a_str_ref {
  const string& str;

 public:
  has_a_str_ref(string const& s) : str(s) {}
  void show() { std::cout << str << std::endl; }
};
int main() {
  const char* s = "abc";
  // const char s[] = "abc"; // not work
  // string s = "abc"; // works
  has_a_str_ref x(s);
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  x.show();
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

What happened behind it?

> PS: compile with `-fsanitize=address`

Comment: `has_a_str_ref` ctor will get a `const&` to a tmp `std::string` created from the char array. Keeping a reference to this tmp (in the `str` member) is not valid.

Comment: Ask yourself - when is your `std::string` created?  When is it destroyed?  A better question - should `has_a_str_ref` _ever_ accept a temporary string as its constructor parameter?

Comment: Side note: `-fsanitize=address` will apply at run-time.

Comment: Note: You can avoid accidents like these by adding a deleted constructor taking an rvalue reference to `std::string`: `has_a_str_ref(string&& s) = delete;`, but this won't 100% guarantee the you're safe: `auto strPtr = std::make_unique<std::string>("abc"); has_a_str_ref x(*strPtr); strPtr.reset(); x.show();`